# No module named web_kanban Odoo V11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, kanban

I've installed Odoo-11 but it's showing error

> No module named web_kanban.

I've added the Addon path in odoo.conf file. Path is correct but it's still showing the error and odoo is unable to start.

Comment: Take a fresh pull of all addons from odoo and then try.

Comment: Resolved just by re-installation. Do you know is it possible to upgrade odooV11 to odooV13?

Comment: No this happens only some base code conflicts.